# SharePoint Online Admin page does not display all the site collection and their owners

Tags: online, microsoft-teams

can someone guide me to achieve following, I am admin on office 365 for SharePoint and Onedrive. When i access https://(companyname)-admin.sharepoint.com i don't see all the site collections, because using `Get-SPOsite -Detailed` i can get the list of sites not viewed from SharePoint Online admin page. I realized that those sites were actually created using Microsoft Teams. Now the question is how do i at least get the current site owners and members if required to change their permission on those sites?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and i found below link kind od useful.
https://www.windowsmanagementexperts.com/ms-teams-sharepoint-online-some-disintegrations-part-2/ms-teams-sharepoint-online-some-disintegrations-part-2.htm